# MVC URL issues (Codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, url, url-routing, path-finding

I'm building a website using Codeigniter and I really like how in the MVC pattern URLs are used to reference controller methods. It seems very logical and intuitive however, I seem to be running in an array of issues with this very pattern!

So I am building an events website and currently I'm passing everything through one main Site controller, passing a number of parameters:

```
public function index($page = NULL, $city = NULL, $type_venue = NULL, $slug = NULL)
{
    // if the page argument is empty show the homepage
    if( ! ($page))
    {
        $page = 'home';
    }

    // create an array for passing to the views
    $data = array(
        'title_city' => $city,
        'title_type_venue' => str_replace('-', ' ', $type_venue),
        'locations' => $this->locations_model->load(),
        'events' => $this->events_model->load($city, $type_venue, $slug),
        'venues' => $this->venues_model->load($city, $slug)
    );

    // construct the page layout with the following views
    $this->load->view('partials/head', $data);
    $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('content/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('partials/footer');
}
```

This works fine, in that it loads content for the following URLs:

```
site.com/events/bristol/open-mic/city-varieties/another-incredible-event
site.com/events/bristol/open-mic/city-varieties/
site.com/events/bristol/open-mic/
site.com/events/bristol/
```

However if I want to pass anything else through this controller that *isn't* an event, i.e. register/user, I have to write a specific route for this!

Worth noting my routing is:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'site/index/$1';
```

I could write separate controllers for each entity, i.e. events, venues, cities but each one would look largely like the above (correct?) in that each would need the parameters to get the data.

My question is - what is the best practice approach for developing long query strings like this? Is a single controller correct? It doesn't feel like it, but then multiple controllers would violate DRY, just because they all need so much similar data. Any help appreciated!

Comment: While it may not be DRY, even if the code is identical I tend to split mine into separate controllers. It reduces the complexity of the code, and means that making changes or adding functionality unique to one section doesn't mean changing code that effects the entire site.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid putting everything into a single controller; even further, in each controller, avoid putting everything into a single index function.

There is no need to write specific controllers for each function in Codeigniter - suggest you read that part again in the manual. Most of your routing will be done automatically for you if you follow the normal guidelines.

The more you try to use a single controller or function, the more you will have to add untestable, unmanageable, unscalable conditional code later.

Comment: I know this, but I'm asking the question because it doesn't feel like separate controllers would be the most efficient way, given that there would be so much repetition. This is quite a specific issue but it's in no way unique, which is why I'm feeling frustrated about the lack of answers I can find.

Comment: not if you set up your controllers correctly. read: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

Comment: Thanks, I was barking up this tree with a MY_Controller setup, I just wasn't sure of how to work with it. Will look at implementing this.